javascript, css and assets are not loading
im developing a website using vanilla html, css and js. My site uses more than one html file, and thats why im trying to organize everything, and its working as expected on the live server (on vscode), but i cant make it work on deploy, i tried on vercel and netlify
the path of the main html file
the errors and how the page looks on vercel deploy
i just specified on the deploy that the main html file is on "pages/main/html", and i dont know why im getting these errors.
there is the main html code and the entire path:
path
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/media-mobile.css" />
    <link
      href="https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/eceba41a00b4b94ea2965371c8dda96c?family=Bernard+MT+Condensed+V2"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&family=Nunito:ital,wght@0,200..1000;1,200..1000&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../../../assets/icon.png" />
    <title>Hotel AuPet</title>
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <header class="header">
        <img
          class="fullLogo"
          src="../assets/header/Hotel-AuPet.png"
          alt="logo"
        />
        <img
          class="logoName"
          src="../assets/header/Hotel-AuPet NOME.png"
          alt="logo-name"
        />
        <img
          class="logoImage"
          src="../assets/header/Hotel-AuPet SEM NOME.png"
          alt="logo-img"
        />
        <div class="info">
          <h2>Viaje com tranquilidade, com o seu cão hospedado conosco</h2>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div class="contacts">
        <div class="contact" onclick="openWindow('insta')">
          <img src="../assets/icons/instagram-icon.png" alt="instagram" />
          <p>hotel_aupet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="contact" onclick="openWindow('zap')">
          <img src="../assets/icons/whatsapp-icon.png" alt="whatsapp" />
          <p>+55 77 9180-6965</p>
        </div>

        <h3>45.700-000 Itapetinga, Bahia, Brasil</h3>
        <div class="pseudoHr"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <div class="carouselContainer">
          <ul class="carousel"></ul>
        </div>

        <ul class="buttons">
          <li onclick="navigateTo('about')">
            <img
              src="../assets/buttons/button-sobre-nos.png"
              alt="button-sobre-nos"
            />
          </li>
          <li onclick="navigateTo('services')">
            <img
              src="../assets/buttons/button-serviços.png"
              alt="button-serviços"
            />
          </li>
          <li onclick="navigateTo('instructions')">
            <img
              src="../assets/buttons/button-instrucoes.png"
              alt="button-instrucoes"
            />
          </li>
          <li onclick="navigateTo('guests')">
            <img
              src="../assets/buttons/button-hospedes.png"
              alt="button-hospedes"
            />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="contacts end">
        <div class="contact" onclick="openWindow('git')">
          <img src="../assets/icons/github-mark.png" alt="instagram" />
          <p>Site desenvolvido por Gabriel G S Rios</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="../script/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


thats not exactly a request actually, there is zero requests on this site, its related to the paths, i dont know why the html are not finding the js, css and assets on the deploy

sorry, i updated the post with the main html code (the page i provided a print)

the structure i made by myselft, no scripts. I tried something different now, i moved the main page files (html, css and js) to the root and added a vercel.json file:
{
"rewrites": [{ "source": "/", "destination": "/main.html" }]
}
and it worked, thanks!
